# Using oak, serving HTML without extension?

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting, deno, oak

Using [`Oak`](https://deno.land/x/oak/), how can I serve HTML without the extension? e.g.
`host:port/home.html` -> `host:port/home`

Here's my current code to render my `public/views` folder:

```
router.get('/:page', async (ctx: Context, next: () => Promise<unknown>) => {
    await send(ctx, ctx.request.url.pathname, {
        root: join(Deno.cwd(), 'public', 'views'),
        extensions: ['htm', 'html']
    });

    await next();
});
```

The `extensions` option is not working or maybe I just use it the wrong way.

### Edit

My fix is currently removing the `.html` extension (e.g. `home.html` -> `home`). Pretty sure there's a better way than this

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to send the file:

```js
router.get('/path', async (ctx:any) => {
    const text = await Deno.readTextFile('./file.html');
    ctx.response.headers.set("Content-Type", "text/html")
    ctx.response.body = text;
});
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! One thing to note though, I had to also do this for any `src` references in the `file.html` as well